# can't add any value in the table after adding foreign key in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have three tables. employee, salary and bill.

==================================

## employee

```
create table employee
(
E_ID int(10) UNSIGNED not null primary key,
E_Name varchar(20) not null,
E_Address varchar(20) not null,
E_Phone varchar(20) not null,
E_HireDate DATETIME not null,
E_Mail varchar(20) not null,
E_Post varchar(20) not null,
E_Dept varchar(20) not null
);
```

==================================

## salary

```
create table salary
(
s_id int(10) UNSIGNED not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
E_ID int(10) UNSIGNED not null,
S_Amount varchar(20) not null,
S_Date DATETIME,
Total_s varchar(20) not null,
foreign key (E_ID) references employee(E_ID)
);
```

They are working fine. I can insert values in these tables and join them with this query-

```
SELECT employee.E_ID as E_ID
     , employee.E_Name as E_Name
     , salary.S_Amount as S_Amount
     , salary.S_Date as S_Date
  from employee
 INNER
  JOIN salary
    ON employee.E_ID = salary.E_ID
```

---

But then I have another table bill.

==================================

## bill

```
create table bill
(
B_ID int(10) UNSIGNED not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
E_ID int(10) UNSIGNED not null,
Electric varchar(20) not null,
Water varchar(20) not null,
Gas varchar(20) not null,
B_Others varchar(20) not null,
B_Date DATETIME,
Total_B varchar(20) not null,
foreign key (E_ID) references employee(E_ID)
);
```

I am trying to insert values with this procedure

```
$eb= $_POST['Electric']; 
$wb= $_POST['Water']; 
$gb= $_POST['Gas']; 
$b_others= $_POST['B_Others']; 
$Total_B= "$eb"+"$wb"+"$gb"+"$b_others"; 

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dhaka"); 
$raw=date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
$date= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($raw)); 

INSERT INTO bill (Electric, Water, Gas, B_Others, B_Date, Total_B) VALUES ('$eb','$wb','$gb', '$b_others', '$date', '$Total_B');
```

I want to join this "bill" table with "salary" table too. But after adding foreign key E_ID in this table i can't insert any value in the "bill" table. I know i have some problem with the foreign key data type and null function. can anyone please help me to fix it.

Comment: Could you add your SQL Error after inserting and an example of INSERT statement you tried to add please ?

Comment: Update SQLFiddle also with some data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc46c3/1

Comment: I am trying to insert values with this procedure.@Delphine   

    $eb= $_POST['Electric'];
    $wb= $_POST['Water'];
    $gb= $_POST['Gas'];
    $b_others= $_POST['B_Others'];
    $Total_B= "$eb"+"$wb"+"$gb"+"$b_others";


    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dhaka");
    $raw=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $date= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($raw));


    INSERT INTO bill (Electric, Water, Gas, B_Others, B_Date, Total_B) VALUES ('$eb','$wb','$gb', '$b_others', '$date', '$Total_B');

Comment: Update your question with this information (and code helper) + SQL error please ! :)

Comment: That has not much to do with your foreign key. If you have a column `E_ID not null`, and your insert statement doesn't include the column `E_ID` (which without a default value means it is `null`), it of course cannot work.

Comment: edit your question to add this additional information which you have provided in the comments.